# Implementing a blocking queue in JavaME: how to optimize it?

Tags: java, java-me, concurrency, producer-consumer

I'm trying to implement a simple blocking queue in Java ME. In JavaME API, the concurrency utilities of Java SE are not available, so I have to use wait-notify like in the old times.

This is my provisional implementation. I'm using `notify` instead of `notifyAll` because in my project there are multiple producers but only a single consumer. I used an object for wait-notify on purpose to improve readability, despite it wastes a reference:

```
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class BlockingQueue {    
        private Vector queue = new Vector();
        private Object queueLock = new Object();    

        public void put(Object o){
            synchronized(queueLock){
                queue.addElement(o);
                queueLock.notify();
            }       
        }

        public Object take(){
            Object ret = null;
            synchronized (queueLock) {
                while (queue.isEmpty()){
                    try {
                        queueLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

                ret = queue.elementAt(0);
                queue.removeElementAt(0);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

My main question is about the `put` method. Could I put the `queue.addElement` line out of the `synchronized` block? Will performance improve if so?

Also, the same applies to `take`: could I take the two operations on `queue` out of the `synchronized block`?

Any other possible optimization?

EDIT:
As @Raam correctly pointed out, the consumer thread can starve when being awakened in `wait`. So what are the alternatives to prevent this? (Note: In JavaME I don't have all these nice classes from Java SE. Think of it as the old Java v1.2)

Comment: Could you try the backport-concurrent libraries instead (http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Thanks, but it says not well tested on Java 1.2. Also I don't need so many classes, just a simple queue.

Comment: No offence but it's still likely to be better tested than a roll-your-own. Also, don't do this `catch (InterruptedException e) {}`; see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The Vector class makes no guarantees to be thread safe, and you should synchronize access to it, like you have done. Unless you have evidence that your current solution has performance problems, I wouldn't worry about it.

On a side note, I see no harm in using `notifyAll` rather than `notify` to support multiple consumers.

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` is used to protect access to shared state and ensure atomicity.

Note that methods of `Vector` are already synchronized, therefore `Vector` protects it own shared state itself. So, your synchronization blocks are only needed to ensure atomicity of your operations.

You certainly cannot move operations on `queue` from the synchronized block in your `take()` method, because atomicity is crucial for correctness of that method. But, as far as I understand, you can move queue operation from the synchronized block in the `put()` method (I cannot imagine a situation when it can go wrong).

However, the reasoning above is purely theoretical, because in all cases you have double synchronization: your synchronize on `queueLock` and methods of `Vector` implicitly synchronize on `queue`. **Therefore proposed optimization doesn't make sense**, its correctness depends on presence of that double synchronization.

To avoid double synchronization you need to synchronize on `queue` as well:

```
synchronized (queue) { ... }
```

Another option would be to use non-synchronized collection (such as `ArrayList`) instead of `Vector`, but JavaME doesn't support it. In this case you won't be able to use proposed optimization as well because synchronized blocks also protect shared state of the non-synchronized collection.

Comment: -1 ArrayList is not available in [J2ME/CLDC](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/package-frame.html "API docs for J2ME java.util - much difference with Java SE"). Other than that, your reasoning looks good

Comment: Are Vector's methods guaranteed to be synchronized? I know that's the case for Java SE, but the reference implementation of MIDP 2.0 Vector (http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Vector.html) does not mention anything related to threads or synchronization.

Comment: @claesv: The following document says that methods of `Vector` are synchronized in CLDC 1.0, not sure how authoritative is it: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.0/cldcapi.pdf

Comment: It doesn't mind if Vector's methods are synchronized or not: AFAIK they are, but that doesn't mean it is thread safe. For my purposes, it is the only collection available. I'm very aware of its poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have performance issues specifically due to garbage collection, I would rather use a linked list than a Vector to implement a queue (first in,first out).

I would also write code that would be reused when your project (or another) gets multiple consumers. Although in that case, you need to be aware that the Java language specifications do not impose a way to implement monitors. In practice, that means that you don't control which consumer thread gets notified (half of the existing Java Virtual Machines implement monitors using a FIFO model and the other half implement monitors using a LIFO model)

I also think that whoever is using the blocking class is also supposed to deal with the InterruptedException. After all, the client code would have to deal with a null Object return otherwise.

So, something like this:

```
/*package*/ class LinkedObject {

    private Object iCurrentObject = null;
    private LinkedObject iNextLinkedObject = null;

    LinkedObject(Object aNewObject, LinkedObject aNextLinkedObject) {
        iCurrentObject = aNewObject;
        iNextLinkedObject = aNextLinkedObject;
    }

    Object getCurrentObject() {
        return iCurrentObject;
    }

    LinkedObject getNextLinkedObject() {
        return iNextLinkedObject;
    }
}

public class BlockingQueue {
    private LinkedObject iLinkedListContainer = null;
    private Object iQueueLock = new Object();
    private int iBlockedThreadCount = 0;

    public void appendObject(Object aNewObject) {
        synchronized(iQueueLock) {
            iLinkedListContainer = new iLinkedListContainer(aNewObject, iLinkedListContainer);
            if(iBlockedThreadCount > 0) {
                iQueueLock.notify();//one at a time because we only appended one object
            }
        } //synchonized(iQueueLock)
    }

    public Object getFirstObject() throws InterruptedException {
        Object result = null;
        synchronized(iQueueLock) {
            if(null == iLinkedListContainer) {
                ++iBlockedThreadCount;
                try {
                    iQueueLock.wait();
                    --iBlockedThreadCount; // instead of having a "finally" statement
                } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                    --iBlockedThreadCount;
                    throw iex;
                }
            }
            result = iLinkedListcontainer.getCurrentObject();
            iLinkedListContainer = iLinkedListContainer.getNextLinkedObject();
            if((iBlockedThreadCount > 0)  && (null != iLinkedListContainer )) {
                iQueueLock.notify();
            }
        }//synchronized(iQueueLock)
        return result;
    }

}
```

I think that if you try to put less code in the synchronized blocks, the class will not be correct anymore.

Comment: Nice one. But what would happen to the consumer thread if it is interrupted? Will it terminate? Should the thread deal with the `InterruptedException` in its `run` method?

Comment: That is definitely one way of handling interruption since it could be caused by the MIDlet being destroyed while one of its thread is blocked.

Answer (score -2):

There seem to be some issues with this approach. You can have scenarios where the consumer can miss notifications and wait on the queue even when there are elements in the queue.
Consider the following sequence in chronological order

T1 - Consumer acquires the queueLock and then calls wait. Wait will release the lock and cause the thread to wait for a notification

T2 - One producer acquires the queueLock and adds an element to the queue and calls notify

T3 - The Consumer thread is notified and attempts to acquire queueLock BUT fails as another producer comes at the same time. (from the notify java doc - The awakened thread will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened thread enjoys no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object.)

T4 - The second producer now adds another element and calls notify. This notify is lost as the consumer is waiting on queueLock.

So theoretically its possible for the consumer to starve (forever stuck trying to get the queueLock) also you can run into a memory issue with multiple producers adding elements to the queue which are not being read and removed from the queue.

Some changes that I would suggest is as follows -

- Keep an upper bound to the number of items that can be added to the queue.
- Ensure that the consumer always read all the elements. [Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306) is a program which shows how the producer - consumer problem can be coded.

Comment: In T4, second producer adds elements, calls notify and releases the lock. then, consumer (it was blocked after being notified) gains the `queueLock` again, it resumes and continues. I see no problem here.

Comment: The consumer can theoretically starve at that point right? It can forever get stuck waiting for the lock if there is a continuous inflow of producers.

Comment: I've been thinking on this since yesterday, and now I see you have a point here. But I can't imagine what alternatives are there to prevent it (and I won't accept tweaking priorities as a solution).

Comment: The link in my answer shows one way of preventing this. They use a boolean in addition to the wait-notify to ensure that the producers do not overrun the consumer. Another option that I can think of is to limit the size of the queue, so if a producer finds that the queue is full it will wait for the queue to get drained before adding. This has the additional advantage of ensuring that the memory usage of the application remains predictable and also gives the single consumer a chance to keep up with the producers.

Comment: On a side note the downvotes are dis-heartening, pointing out not so obvious issues is surely not a wrong thing?

Comment: I read the awfully formatted code on your link. Doesn't look good to me. That boolean is not thread-safe. But it gave me the idea of using a counter to limit the number of max producers entering at a time, and make them wait on another lock until consumer releases counts.

Comment: About the downvotes, you shouldn't worry. I'm thankful for your answer, it was interesting.